# Error: "The process cannot access.... because it is being used by another process. " in Delete Image

Tags: c#, error-handling

I know others had a similar problem but my problem is specific for image...
I have an image function like below:

```
        static public string Setimage(PictureBox pictureBox, OpenFileDialog ofd,string nameform,string folderform)
    {
        ofd.Title = "Select Pictures";
        ofd.Filter = "Pictures(*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png | All file (*.*)| *.*";

        ofd.DefaultExt = ".jpg"; // Default file extension 
        string namefile = "";
        // Process open file dialog box results 

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           // try
            //{
                string fileName = ofd.FileName;
                if (ofd.SafeFileName.Length <= 50)
                    if (Image.FromFile(fileName).Width >= 640 && Image.FromFile(fileName).Height >= 480)
                    {
                        namefile = ofd.SafeFileName;
                        if (namefile != "Null_0_Null" || namefile != null)
                        {
                         string oldPath = @ofd.FileName;
                         string newFileName = namefile;
                         newpath = Application.StartupPath + @"\userpictures\" + @"Apartment\";
                                    deladdress = newpath + folderform + @"\" + @newFileName;
                                    Random rand = new Random();
                                    string pp=newpath+folderform;
                                   // string pdest;

                                    #region Check Directory And File To copy
                                    if (Directory.Exists(newpath + folderform))
                                    {
                                        if (!File.Exists(newpath + folderform + @"\" + @newFileName))
                                            File.Copy(oldPath, newpath + folderform + @"\" + @newFileName);
                                       // else
                                       // {
                                          //  File.Delete(newpath + folderform + @"\" + @newFileName);
                                         //   File.Copy(oldPath, newpath + folderform + @"\" + @newFileName);
                                        //}
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath + folderform);
                                        File.Copy(oldPath, newpath + folderform + @"\" + @newFileName);
                                    }
                                    #endregion
                                    pictureBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(newpath + folderform + @"\" + @newFileName);
                        }
                        else { MessageBox.Show("filename" + namefile + "Not valid"); }
                    }
                    else { MessageBox.Show("Size of file not valid"); }
                else { MessageBox.Show("size of name file not valid"); }
           // }
           // catch { MessageBox.Show("your file that you selected is not valid please select anyone."); }
        }
        return namefile;
    }
```

For loading image I have this function:

```
 static public void loadimage(PictureBox pictureBox, string img, string nameform, string folderform)
    {
        try
        {

            if (img != "Null_0_Null")
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\userpictures\" + nameform + @"\" + folderform + @"\" + img))
                {
                    pictureBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\filepictures\\default4.PNG");
                }
                else
                {
                  pictureBox.BackgroundImage =Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\userpictures\" + nameform + @"\" + folderform + @"\" + img);
                }
                }
        catch { }
    }
```

In my form I call this functions. For set image I write a private string in my form:

```
string img1;
```

And for loading image in my form load write this:

```
loadimage(pictureBox1, "Blue hills.jpg","me", "Apartment");
img1 = "Blue hills.jpg";
```

For `Setimage` I have this:

```
img1=Setimage(pictureBox1, openFileDialog1,"me", "Apartment");
```

And when I use this code for delete image show me error "process can not be access ..."

```
 System.IO.File.Delete("image path");
```

Comment: I do hope that `catch { }` isn't in your *real* code... (And that it's indented rather more readably, ideally with more convention method names too...)

Comment: [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) is disposable (and holds locks on the original image file), but you're leaking them all over the place with those `FromFile` methods that don't even assign to a local variable.

Comment: you aren't closing a file handle somewhere. Use the `using` block and you won't have to worry about this any more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `Image.FromFile`, that will open a file handle to that file and *keep it open* until the image is disposed.

You should:

- Only call `Image.FromFile` once and reuse the object in `Setimage` (you're loading it twice in a single `if` condition...)
- Dispose of every `Image` when you're done with it
- Dispose of the old `BackgroundImage` before you set the new one

So long as you dispose of every `Image` which is related to the file before you delete the file, you should be okay.